# How to have git and virtualenv aware colors in terminal?

Tags: command-line, fonts, gnome-terminal, git, colors

I am watching "Building Web APIs with Flask" [video](http://player.oreilly.com/videos/9781491911938?toc_id=190358) on Oreilly from Miguel Grinberg. His terminal is colorful and shows different colors for virtualenv name and git branch name. I want to have the same terminal **with the same colors and fonts** in my Ubuntu 14.04. How can I do that?

Here is a screenshot from one scene of his video:

[image]

Comment: You're looking for coloured prompts that have git branches/virtualenv names? The same colours might be a bit difficult, but the rest can be done.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean clearly but I want to have colors assigned to the name of virtualenv that I am using, for example in above picture the virtualenv's name is in gray while the rest of the prompt is cyan and the git branch name is green.

Comment: @muru Moreover the rest of terminal is also colorful. Look at "application/json" which has color and somehow the terminal colors are like an IDE with syntax highlight.

Comment: The line `(venv) oreilly ... (master) $` is called a [bash prompt](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/). The [`http`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/http.1.html) command naturally does syntax colouring. The two are independent.

Comment: Look at this answer for a prompt that's close to what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23410110/2072269

Comment: @muru Thanks, it is similar to what I need. Your comments and that question answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`http`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/http.1.html) does syntax coloring naturally.

To set a bash prompt like this one, add the contents of [this file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8309019/) to your `~/.bashrc`.
It is an adaptation of the prompt from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23410110/2072269). I have changed the colours, added couple more [colour variables](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) and parentheses.

Comment: There is an error in the provided file. Line 35 should change to: **datevar=`date +%p`
  if [ -n $datevar ] && [ "$datevar" = "PM" ]; then**
or something similar, otherwise you will get bash errors while entering git directories.

Comment: Just for record: The script has more bugs that I was not able to fix. It breaks terminal's history navigation.

Comment: I have experienced neither problem.

Comment: Not every environment is identical to another one.